# How many homomorphisms from Z5 to D8 and Z5 to D10

Tags: group-theory

[image]

I think the first part is related to the isomorphism theorem but I'm not exactly sure how you use it in this context.
I am struggling to understand the concept of a normal/quotient group so an explanation or an example for part 2 would also be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: a homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}_5$ is entirely determined by the value it takes on a generator, and this value must have order $5$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\phi$ be a homomorphism from $\Bbb{Z}_5$ to $D_8$.
By first isomorphism theorem, $\Bbb{Z}_5/\ker \phi\cong \phi(D_8)$.
So we have $5=|\ker \phi||\phi(D_8)|$
Since $|\phi(D_8)|$ divides $5$ and $8$, $|\phi(D_8)|=1$.
Hence $\phi$ is the trivial map which sends every elements of $\Bbb{Z}_5$ to identity of $D_8$.

For the second part, write $\Bbb{Z}_5=\langle x\rangle$ and $D_10=\langle r,s|r^5=s^2=(rs^2)=1\rangle$.
The five homomorphisms would be defined by sending the generator $x$ to $r^i$ where $i=0,1,2,3,4$.